# cannot load certificate : while run 'docker compose up' inside docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, jenkins, docker-compose

i have 2 containers : nginx and jenkins.
nginx container built by following docker-compose file:

```py
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginxDF # copy nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
```

jenkins container build by this:

```py
version: '3.7'

services:
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: jenkinsDF
    container_name: 'jenkins_docker'
    restart: always
    user: root
    ports:
      - '8081:8080'
      - '50200:50000'
    volumes:
      - './jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
      - '/home/ubuntu/proj:/home/proj'
```

and my nginx.conf:

```py
...
  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    
      server_name {mydomain};
   
    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      allow all;
      root /var/www/certbot;
    }
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
  }
  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name {mydomain};
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/{mydomain}/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/{mydomain}/privkey.pem;
   ...
  }
...
```

all those file located in '/home/ubuntu/proj'

running "docker compose up -d -build" command at '/home/ubuntu/proj' works fine as well..
but when i do this inside on a mounted volume('/home/proj' in jenkins container), 'nginx' container stops with this log:

```
cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/{mydomain}/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed 
(SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:
fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/{mydomain}/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
```

i checked inside with 'docker exec -it jenkins bash' and all .pem files looks just fine.

I'm just curious why this happens and if this can be fixed.
Perhaps referring the mounted volume once more occur this problem...

Comment: Does this path exists: /home/ubuntu/proj/data/certbot/conf/live/{mydomain}/fullchain.pem?

Comment: Check that in your nginx's container too

Comment: @C1sc0 yes. .pem files exist both '/home/ubuntu/proj/data/certbot/conf/live/{mydomain}/fullchain.pem'(ouside of container) and ''/home/proj/data/certbot/conf/live/{mydomain}/fullchain.pem"(in jenkins container). it seems the problem solved when i remove volumes option and just add 'COPY .pem file' in 'nginxDF' file. Maybe in the process of executing docker compose, referring mounted volume in jenkins container does not seem to work as expected. i still wonder why.... thx for comment btw